# How to delete .filepart files in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

There's incomplete .filepart files in a Tests folder in SAS Enterprise Guide and I would like to delete all of them.

When I try to right click and delete, it gives me an error saying "Insufficient authorization to access /.../Tests/file.filepart"

I also tried doing this and it didn't do anything.

```
%macro check(file);
%if %sysfunc(fileexist(&file)) ge 1 %then %do;
   %let rc=%sysfunc(filename(temp,&file));
   %let rc=%sysfunc(fdelete(&temp));
%end; 
%else %put The file &file does not exist;
%mend check; 

%check(/.../Tests/file.filepart)
```

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient authorization means that the user running the SAS script does not have write permission to the file you are deleting.

Did a different process / user create the .filepart files? If you have authorization to change permissions then you can use the `chmod` command prior to deletion to give yourself write permission (using `system()` or `call system` or `x` within SAS itself. If not, then this is really a system issue and you need have your admins take care of the issue for you.